# What species is Vilix'pran and what do we know about him?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In DS9 "Heart of Stone":

> SISKO: I see you've put in a request to reassign Ensign **Vilix'pran**
>   from cargo inspection.
>
> BASHIR: I think that would be best. Given his condition, I don't want
>   him coming in contact with any hazardous materials.
>
> SISKO: His condition?
>
> BASHIR: **Vilix'pran** is budding. His buds are undergoing
>   **individuation** in just over a month.
>
> SISKO: You mean he's **pregnant**?
>
> BASHIR: Twins.
>
> SISKO: Reassignment granted. I'll have make sure I offer my
>   congratulations to the ensign next time I see him.
>
> BASHIR: O'Brien and I are throwing him a baby shower in a couple of
>   days. I think it would mean a lot to him if you were there.
>
> SISKO: Are you getting him anything?
>
> BASHIR: O'Brien's building him a **hatchling pond** and I've put an
>   order in with Garak for some new baby clothes.
>
> SISKO: Count me in.
>
> BASHIR: Aye, sir

It's kind of a funny conversation because in our species this would normally a be a conversation between females not males. Sisko and Bashir both use male pronouns to refer to this person implying he is male. Bashir uses the term individuation implying it's asexual reproduction. Bashir also refers to a hatchling pond which would infer this person is possibly amphibious.

In a later DS9 episode "Apocalypse Rising" we learn that he's budding again and litters are generally between 2 and 12 offspring.

In DS9 episode "Business As Usual" Jake Sisko is babysitting the hatchlings and needs to make sure their wings don't get tangled.

Do we know what species Vilix'pran is? Do we know anything about him and his species other than what I mentioned? Do we know what they look like?

STU or EU information is fine. If you find a picture of him please post it.

Comment: “in our species this would normally a be a conversation between females not males” — maybe your species, buddy.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I knew somebody was going to pick on that comment. How many baby showers have you been invited too? Or am I being presumptuous in assuming Paul is a "male" name.

Comment: too many to count! “Species” encompasses all humans though — in many cultures, I’m sure you’re right, but all of humanity?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite read the correct answer below. It was supposed to be comical, which it was. I was laughing. Read the comments below as well.

Comment: ha ha! Men and babies! Men caring about children! Ha ha! Hilarious.

Comment: Well I guess the writers and others have a different sense of humour then you do @PaulD.Waite. Since that was how it was written and how it was taken, I guess we're wrong and you're right. I wouldn't imply that baby showers are indicative of caring for a child. If that's the case I guess 99.999999999 percent of all men are uncaring towards their children.

Comment: @JMFB: "How many baby showers have you been invited too?" - In my culture, there is no such thing as baby showers, but I have once attended one at friends of mine from an anglo-saxon culture. The guests seemed to be evenly distributed across both sexes, though. If your statements are based on the assumption that males do not usually attend baby showers, please explain that briefly, as otherwise, the respective statements can be quite confusing even for visitors who happen to know the local custom of "baby showers".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Traditionally, baby showers were given only for the family's first child, and **only women were invited.**
According to etiquette authority Miss Manners, because the party centers on gift-giving, the baby shower is typically arranged and hosted by a close friend rather than a member of the family, since it is considered rude for families to beg for gifts on behalf of their members. However, this custom varies by culture or region and in some it is expected and customary for a close **female family member**... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_shower

Comment: @O.R.Mapper would you like me to give you another ten links to show that baby showers are traditionally for woman. This is not really disputable. If someone wants to invite a man or men that's their prerogative. But it's not generally how it's done, traditionally how it's done, and is pretty rare.

Comment: @JMFB: Thank you for the reference. Please include that in your text next time, it is less confusing that way than if you assume the whole world knows the traditions of your particular place.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper NP, just curious what part of the world are you from. You didn't fill out your profile fully. If you go to that link it lists a lot of countries and what their traditions are. In almost every country baby showers are exclusively for women.

Comment: @JMFB: I'm from Germany, where "baby showers" are mostly unheard of. At least three of the examples in the list of countries refer to events for both genders in the respective cultures. Also, versions of the article in other languages contain statements such as (Spanish) "Most invite only women, although there is no fixed rule." or (Portuguese) "Traditionally, only women were invited. Nowadays, however, many people opt for organizing baby showers involving both parents and/or invite men". (Note that I am not claiming you are wrong to say women-only baby showers are the norm where you live, ...

Comment: ... it's just much easier to follow statements such as "It's kind of a funny conversation because in our species this would normally a be a conversation between females not males." if the context is made clear to "outsiders" :) )

Comment: " Paul is a "male" name." Names in our species are not *sexed*, they are *gendered*. Female people with the *masculine* name "Michael", *boys* named "Sue" etc. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vilix'pran species is never stated in the shows. He also appears to never get a species name in EU works either. All we know about him is that at least the young have wings, and he himself supposedly as a male, reproduces asexually. Other things we know is that he can have multiple kids as once, and is speculated at to have at least 6 children. Every single mainstream resource about star trek also states that his species is unknown. It appears he was made to be a form of gag.

[image: Quotes about Vilix'pran, Part 1]
[image: Quotes about Vilix'pran, Part 2]

this is taken from the [Deep Space Nine Companion.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Companion)

Comment: I read memory alpha and wiki. Everything you posted I wrote above. I was just wondering if there was any other information about him from other sources. Maybe there's writers/authors notes, novels, comics, or something I don't have access to.

Comment: my picture/quotes are from the writers of the show, so thats your definitive answer, he was a fun joke.

Comment: Thank you for that. I figured it was something like that. I was laughing when they started talking about a baby shower. I actually have a friend who had a baby shower for men, it was pretty comical. Most of the gifts were gift cards, lol. Nobody knew what to do at a male baby shower.

Comment: From the Star Trek Encyclopedia (third Edition); https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0mX.png